# asp .net partial rendering

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm new to asp .net and have one interesting question about async callbacks.

Is it possible to change lifecycle of a page so as to cancel instantiation of all the objects in object tree except those certain controls that actually take part in my rendering process? For example, if I want to handle event for a specific textbox in ajax style, I don't want all grids and other big ui controls on my page to be created each time postback happens. That would be real benefit in performance of asp .net ajax. Does anyone know?

Comment: Maybe that is possible to do somehow at PreInit stage of page lifecycle?

Comment: You need to change either your header or your question. Is your question about rendering, about async callback or object instantiating in asp.net?

Comment: My question relate to all of that, ibram. UpdatePanel is a good thing and, of course, I want to use it. But they cause instantiation of the whole page during each postback!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this with

1. Ajax Control Toolkit, for several events of some controls: AutoComplete, Filtering, etc..
2. a third party callback implementation like [ComponentArt's one](http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/callback/programming/bypassing_pageLifeCycle/WebForm1.aspx)
3. A jQuery call to a WebMethod in the page

Comment: No, I need to use the above-mentioned technique with any controls.

Comment: then I would use a third party callback implementation, like ComponentArt's. See the link i provided you